# How to post file with new html form from append in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have issue about the picture doesn't send to server. ok let me to tell about my code. I have code jQuery which the code append edit modal to container edit. the below code is container edit which to put edit modal from server

```
<div id="container-edit"></div>
```

and then I have called ajax which to get some code modal edit form and the result this

```
<form method=post enctype="multipart/form-data" action=gotolinkedit>
    <input type=text name="example1" value="somevalue" />
    <input type=file name="picture" />
    <input type=submit name="btnSubmit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and when I submit, the input example1 receive my input, but the input file picture doesn't get my upload picture.

and this my controllers code

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\FrontEnd\MarketPlace;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ListOrderServices extends Controller
{
public function editServices(Request $request) {
    if ($request->file('picture') == null) {
        return dd($request->input('picture'));
      }
    }
}
```

and the return is null.

how to solve this problem?

Comment: And where is your controller code?

Comment: Change the form enctype to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. You can get the file out in the controller using `$request->file('picture')`

Comment: i have updated my post.

Comment: i am already to use enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

```
public function editServices(Request $request) {

    if (!empty($request->file('picture'))) {

      dd($request->file('picture'));
      }
    }
```

Comment: i wrote code agaiin, this is just example code. sorry i typo

Comment: i have updated my post my result, and then the result null.

Comment: Did you update the **editServices** function as mentioned above. Also please check, what is output of dd($request->all());

Comment: what it's different? it same result the file picture doesn't catch the request

`array:1 ["example1"=> "tested code"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function editServices(Request $request) {
$file = $request->file('picture');

if (!empty($file)) {

    dd($file);

  }
}
```

Comment: same result bro, i think, the file request picture doesn't sent to server. i am confused. how to happened this? even though I have added code in the form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: then use  laravel form on the place of html form and their just write  files=>true

Comment: I didn't use html form laravel bro. it's takes time to change all of the code.

Comment: no bro just add a laravel form facade after that you can implement laravel form

Comment: use the request file in the insert is working, but in the edit not working because form edit i call from ajax. and then i put the code result response html to container-edit.

Comment: it's not different bro. i think, this is not bug from laravel.

Comment: see my post bro, there is the response from ajax

Comment: if you are using ajax their is button type submit that will be button type

Comment: bro, i have jQuery post which you can look my code. i already to code submit into click button which the click button is submit to. 

if the submit didn't working, exactly the all of data is not sending right?

but, this case example, i uploaded my picture, and then in laravel there is not catching my file? how to happened? i confused.

Answer (score 0):

So that means, that the problem is on javascript. Could you show it? 
I can advice you to use FormData object to send files on server.

```
var formData = new FormData;

   var files = input.eq(0)[0].files[0];// your file input element

   if (!files) {
       return;
   }

   formData.append("picture", files);

$.ajax({
       url:urlUpload,
       data:formData, ...
```

Maybe not very clean, but try this:

```
$("body").on('click', '.save-data-services', function () {

    var form = $(this).closest('form');

    var fileInput = form.find('input[name="picture"]');

    var formData = new FormData;

    var files = fileInput.eq(0)[0].files[0];

   if (!files) {
       return;
   }

   formData.append("file", files);
   formData.append("example1", form.find('input[name="example1"]').val());

   var urlUpload = form.attr('action');

   $.ajax({
       url:urlUpload,
       data:formData,
       type:"POST",

       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function(data){

            console.log(data);

       },
       error: function(obj,code)
       {
           console.log(obj,code);
       }
   });

   return false;
```

});

Comment: Why not to try the idea with FormData?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.save-data-services', function(e) {
   $(this).parent().prev().children().submit();
   e.preventDefault();
});
$(".save-ads").on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

just using submit bro.